# Не проверяет числа на четность

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

int s,n;
double pr = 1;

int mas[n];
cout << "vvedite razmer masiva: "; cin >> n;

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    mas[n] = rand() % 10;      
    cout << i << ": "<< mas[n] << endl;   
    }

for (int b = 0; b<n; b++){ // проверка на четность
    if (n % 2 == 0){
    pr += mas[n];
    }       
}
cout << "Rezult: " << pr << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Программа проверяет элемент массива на четность и просто суммирует все элементы массива.

Comment: Она у вас проверяет на четность количество элементов... Вернее, вы от нее этого хотите, но вообще-то программа - набор ерунды. Например, массив неизвестного размера. Работа *только* с одним элементом массива, который находится за его границами (теоретически; практически это просто не будет работать).

Comment: Ууу, опять эта ошибка. Размер массива не меняется после его создания, если поменять `n`. Сначала нужно прочитать `n`, а потом создавать массив.

Comment: Дальше: `mas[n]` - ерунда. `n` - это ведь размер массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде присутствуют многочисленные ошибки(читайте комментарии), поэтому вот корректный пример реализации данного алгоритма.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *mas, n, sum;
  sum = 0;
  system("chcp 1251");
  system("cls");
  cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
  cin >> n;
  mas = new int[n];
  for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
 {
    cout << "mas[" << i << "]= ";
    cin >> mas[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
  {
    if (mas[i] % 2 == 0)
      sum += mas[i];
  }
  cout << "Сумма четных элементов массива равна " << sum;
  cin.get(); cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: что объявляется в `*mas` и зачем позже писать `mas = new int[n]`? почему просто не написать `int mas[n]`

Comment: Это указатель на объект(один из вариантов инициализации массива). Но в данном случае можешь использовать и классический вариант: `int mas[n]`

Comment: я попробовал изменить `sum += mas[i]` на `sum *= mas[i]` и стало выводить 0  можеш объяснить почему? я почти не знаю c++

Comment: * - указатель. Если ты новичок в c++ то лучше не трогай эту тему пока что, она может оказаться тяжела для восприятия

Comment: А разве это не знак умножения? или как тогда умножить а не сложить числа?

Comment: А вы об этом, извините не так вас понял. Я думаю что проблема у вас в том что начальное значение sum 0. Соответственно 0 * на любое число 0. Если действительно в этом проблема то измените с нуля на единицу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100199/discussion-between-mangyst-and-daniell0).

Comment: `mas[i] & 1 == 1` более эфективный подход для проверки четности

Comment: @raviga В таком случаи он будет считать только не четные

Comment: @mangyst это да, но можно `!(number & 1 == 1)`